# Having a ball re-selecting PHP make config settings...FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, php53

I am installing PHP 5.3 and having accidentally hit enter when selecting options failed to enable a module.

After the installation `make` no longer gives me options but continues with saved options.

When I run `make config` it says there are no options to configure.

How do we get back to the initial options screen?

Where are these config files saved?

Comment: Where are you running `make config` from?

Comment: /usr/ports/www/php53-session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do we get back to the initial options screen?

You need to reconfigure the `php53` port, but it seems you've been trying to reconfigure a module instead. Perform the following

```
cd /usr/ports/lang/php53
make config
```

You can also use `make showconfig`, `make rmconfig` to show and delete options, respectively.

> Where are these config files saved?

`/var/db/ports/<portname>/options`. But don't edit this manually. Use the dialog interface.

Note also that if you use a tool such as `portmaster` you can force reinstall the port and its dependencies. `portmaster` has a `--force-config` flag which makes the options dialog appear again even if you haven't removed the config.